# how to display a variable in the text box C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

hello i am facing a small problem and its by displaying a variable in the text box after checking another check box here is my code :

```
public partial class AccessoriesForm : Form
    {
        public AccessoriesForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Total(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double TotalPrice = 0;
            if (CagesCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                TotalPrice += 0.75;

                TotalPriceTextBox.Text = TotalPrice.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

// please help

Comment: Whats the problem you're facing? What happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: What's the problem?  Where is `Total` getting called?

Comment: Also, your TotalPrice will always be 0 or 0.75 since you're declaring it inside the method.

Comment: see i have a check box and another text box and i want the total Price to display in the TextBox when i check the CheckBox .

Comment: Did you attach an event to the checkbox click event handler?

Comment: no iam actually new to this , how do i get the text box to increment its value everytime i check a check box .

Comment: attached an event like u said everything works fine thank you .

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your problem is you are defining `TotalPrice` inside of your method, so every time you see  `0.75`  in the `TextBox`.Put the definition outside of your method then it should work fine.

```
double TotalPrice = 0;
private void Total(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (CagesCheckBox.Checked)
     {
         TotalPrice += 0.75;

         TotalPriceTextBox.Text = TotalPrice.ToString();
     }
}
```

Also don't forget to attach your event handler.You can use `CheckedChanged` event for this  and you can attach it in your constructor:

```
public AccessoriesForm()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     CagesCheckBox.CheckedChanged += Total;
}
```